# Can Firebirds SELECT FIRST accept a variable?

Tags: sql, firebird

http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-first-skip

The manual says that FIRST accepts "Any expression evaluating to an integer."  Shouldn't this mean a variable too?

In the following stored procedure, I get an error trying to supply `:DAYS` to `FIRST`.

```
Token unknown - line 10, column 18
:
```

Line 10 column 18 is the `:` in front of DAYS...

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE P_STOCK_MDA 
 ( STOCK BIGINT, TRADE_DATE DATE, DAYS SMALLINT ) 
RETURNS 
 ( AVG_CLOSE NUMERIC(6,2) )
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(STOCK_ADJ_CLOSE) FROM (
    SELECT FIRST :DAYS STOCK_ADJ_CLOSE
    FROM STOCK_DAILY yd 
    WHERE yd.STOCK_STOCK=:STOCK AND yd.TRADE_DATE<=:TRADE_DATE
    ORDER BY yd.TRADE_DATE DESC
  ) INTO AVG_CLOSE;
END^
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose the parameter in parentheses to get it working:

```
SELECT FIRST (:DAYS) STOCK_ADJ_CLOSE
```

Full code:

```
SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE P_STOCK_MDA 
 ( STOCK BIGINT, TRADE_DATE DATE, DAYS SMALLINT ) 
RETURNS 
 ( AVG_CLOSE NUMERIC(6,2) )
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(STOCK_ADJ_CLOSE) FROM (
    SELECT FIRST (:DAYS) STOCK_ADJ_CLOSE
    FROM STOCK_DAILY yd 
    WHERE yd.STOCK_STOCK=:STOCK AND yd.TRADE_DATE<=:TRADE_DATE
    ORDER BY yd.TRADE_DATE DESC
  ) INTO AVG_CLOSE;
END^

SET TERM ; ^
```

The documentation does say :

> If `<int-expr>` is an integer literal or a query parameter, the “`()`” may be omitted

However I assume this only applies to the `?` query parameter in DSQL, not to the named parameters in PSQL.